# Support for Python and Django autocompletion in Sublime Text

Tags: python, django, sublimetext3, pycharm, sublimetext

I have been using Pycharm for a while as only an editor for Python and Django development. I love its support for autocompletion. However, I don't really use any of its IDE features, as I most frequently use my Mac terminal instead (eg for git).

Sublime Text looks like a good and simple/fast editor. Does anyone know what plugins support the autocompletion like Pycharm does (also for Django)?

Thanks!

Comment: Help/What can I ask?: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow". Sorry, I get why you're asking, but gotta flag this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Djaneiro supports Django syntax and autocompletion. Anaconda will do for Python autcompletion, and you can use sublimelinter with pyflakes or pep for linting. This site may also be of interest to you:

https://realpython.com/blog/python/setting-up-sublime-text-3-for-full-stack-python-development/

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a Django-specific plugin for Sublime Text I can recommend [Djaneiro](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Djaneiro). Its main features are adding:

- syntax highlighting for Django HTML templates; and
- code completion snippets for Django HTML templates and Python files.

It sounds like you'd be more interested in the code completion snippets but I found that the improved syntax highlighting for Django templates is also super useful.

The code completion snippets added by Djaneiro are quite comprehensive. For example, you can insert an `{% if _____ %} {% endif %}` block by typing `if` as an abbreviation and hitting the auto-complete key (`Tab` by default).

If you'd like to learn a bit more about Djaneiros pros and cons I wrote this review for it a while ago: https://dbader.org/blog/sublime-text-djaneiro-review