# Sublime Text 4: Support for Django autocompletion

Tags: django, sublimetext4

I'm looking for a way to implement Django's autocompletion and hints. I'm aware that it's possible in [**Sublime Text 3**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31571077/support-for-python-and-django-autocompletion-in-sublime-text). I'm looking at how to do it in the **Sublime Text 4**.

For example, I'm unable to use [**Djanerio**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Djaneiro) in Sublime package browser going: preferences -> Package Control: Djanerio.
It doesn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to see if you already have it installed: **`Preferences → Package Control → Package Control: List Packages`**. It won't show up if you just do **`Preferences → Package Control → Package Control: Djaneiro`** (*note the spelling*). If it's not installed yet, choose **`Preferences → Package Control → Package Control: Install → Djaneiro`**. It should work perfectly fine on Sublime Text 4.

I also highly recommend checking out [`Anaconda`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Anaconda) (not at all related to the Anaconda Python distribution). Once it's set up properly, it's incredibly useful. Keep in mind that Djaneiro was last updated 5 years ago, and most of the code is from 8-11 years ago. An ***awful*** lot has changed in Django since then.

Comment: It doesn't work, unfortunately. I don't see an option to install **Package Control: List Packages**. What's more, it doesn't have any sense too. I need to find something more up-to-date. Is there anything else that might be used for Django (besides **Djaneiro**)?

Comment: @PawełPedryc sorry, my instructions were a little unclear. When I wrote `Preferences → Package Control → Package Control: Install → Djaneiro`, I meant select `Preferences → Package Control`, then wait for the menu to show up, then select `Package Control: Install`, hit Enter, then type in `Djaneiro` and hit Enter again. As far as something other than Djaneiro, [`Django Syntax`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Django%20Syntax) highlights Django HTML templates, but not `.py` files. Take a look through [these results](https://packagecontrol.io/search/django) on Package Control if you want.